# How can I obtain substrings from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, indexing, substring

I have a string that looks like this:

```
var stringOriginal = "72157632110713449SomeDynamicText";
```

I want to separate this string into two substrings:

- One substring is the first 17 digits
- One substring is the rest of the string

I want these stored in two separate variables, like this:

```
var string1 = "72157632110713449"; //First static 17 digits
var string2 = "SomeDynamicText";   // Dynamic Text
```

Comment: Do you know if the first part is a specific length, i.e. 17 ? Or, is there any other specific logic to the first and second part of the string?

Comment: You should accept answers of those who answered first.  Please take a look again at the answers again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will split the string into vars given that the first 17 characters always go into string1 and the remainder into string2.

```
var string1 = stringOriginal.substring(0,17);
var string2 = stringOriginal.substring(17,stringOriginal.length);
```

Comment: Are you sure about this one `(0,16)`? I think it should be `(0, 17)`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your string is fixed, you can use the [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) or [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) string functions. The two are very similar:

- `substr(start, length)` obtains a value from the `start` index to a specified `length` (or to the end, if unspecified)
- `substring(start, end)` obtains a value from the `start` index to the `end` index (or the end, if unspecified)

So, one way you could do it by mixing and matching the two, is like this:

```
var string1 = stringOriginal.substring(0, 17);
# interestingly enough, this does the same in this case
var string1 = stringOriginal.substr(0, 17);

var string2 = stringOriginal.substr(17);
```

If, however, you need a more sophisticated solution (e.g. not a fixed length of digits), you could try using a regex:

```
var regex   = /(\d+)(\w+)/;
var match   = regex.exec(stringOriginal);
var string1 = match[1]; // Obtains match from first capture group
var string2 = match[2]; // Obtains match from second capture group
```

Of course, this adds to the complexity, but is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
string1 = stringOriginal.substring(0, 17);
string2 = stringOriginal.substring(17, stringOriginal.length);
```

or

```
string2 = stringOriginal.substring(17); 
//Second parameter is optional. The index where to stop the extraction. 
//If second parameter is omitted, it extracts the rest of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to split the string by separating initial digits from the rest regardless of length :

```
 string = string.match (/^(\d+)(.*)/) || [string, '', ''];
```

`string[1]` will hold the initial digits, `string[2]` the rest of the string, the original string will be in `string[0]`.

If `string` does not start with a digit, `string[0]` will hold the original string and `string[1]` and `string[2]` will be empty strings.

By changing the code to :

```
 string = string.match (/^(\d*)(.*)/);
```

strings containing no initial digits will have `string[1]` empty and `string[2]` will have the same value as `string[0]`, i.e the initial string. In this case there is no need to handle the case of a failing match.